# 標準モジュール及びフォームの全解放

Tags: vba

複数のエクセルファイルで複数の標準モジュール、フォームを開放したいです。

いろいろ調べましたが、当問題を解決するロジックは不定期間後に再度実施する必要性が出てきているため、ロジック自体は消えないで欲しいというのが望みです。

複数標準モジュール開放ロジックをブック等に作り、開放したい対象をディレクトリにまとめておく必要性があるという条件が最適ですが、特に条件は問いませんのでよろしくお願い致します。

---

コメントへの返信:

> 「開放」とはどのような行為なのでしょうか？

標準モジュール、フォームを右クリックして解放を選ぶことで削除する行為を指しています。

> 「当問題を解決するロジック」が何を意味するのかも説明してください。ひょっとすると、モジュールやフォームに定義されたfun‌​ctionやsubの事ですか？

標準モジュール、フォームを削除する仕組みでvbaで実現できるのなら当方も分かりやすいのですが、
 他に実現方法が有るのであれば手段を制限しないようこのような記述にしています。

Comment: 「開放」とはどのような行為なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「当問題を解決するロジック」が何を意味するのかも説明してください。ひょっとすると、モジュールやフォームに定義されたfunctionやsubの事ですか？

Comment: 質問者さんはもう訪れてないようですし、必要なものまで削るかもしれませんが、ここ [Excelファイルからマクロを完全に削除する方法（Excel97～2016まで共通）](http://www.start-macro.com/55/w/s006.html) の裏技で「拡張子を変えてセーブする」を試すのもいいかも。

Answer (score 0):

標準モジュール、フォームを削除する行為は、プログラムの改変に当たります。
VBA実行中にプログラムを弄ると、実行がリセットされます。

Excelの別インスタンスで実行できるかは、試してみないと分からない。